# Where should Shake Share's .shake.cache directory be stored?

Tags: shake-build-system

We're planning to start using Shake's share functionality more heavily, and one question that has come up is where to store the "share" cache.

Should it be (ignored by VCS) in the code repository so that it gets regularly cleaned, or is the expectation that it should exist somewhere independent elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is still fairly new so I don't think we really know what is best. My guess would be outside the VCS, on a shared drive or similar, and then perhaps prune it every week or so. But I'd be curious to get your answer in a few weeks time.